# Batch: ignore processing of file having current date as part of its name or file created on current date

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a requirement to search for files having date stamp on their name and zip them.
The zipping part is working fine. But, I need to ignore the file which has current date stamp as part of its name. File name pattern is like below :

```
filename_2013-04-18.log
filename_2013-04-19.log
```

So, if 2013-04-19 is the current date, the batch script should ignore the 2nd file.
I am just a beginner, so can anyone help? I have reached till here:

```
for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /T') do set year=%%c
for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /T') do set month=%%a
for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /T') do set day=%%b
set CurrentDate=%year%-%month%-%day%
echo %CurrentDate%
FOR %%c in (%1%filename*.*) DO (
echo %%c
::code to ignore file with CurrentDate
::code to zip older file(s)
)
```

`echo %%c` is printing the file name correctly. And, the code to zip is also working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little simplicication:

```
for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /T'
  ) do set year=%%c&set month=%%a&set day=%%b&set CurrentDate=%%c-%%a-%%b
echo %CurrentDate%
FOR %%c in (%1%filename*.*) DO (
 echo %%c
 REM code to ignore file with CurrentDate
 ECHO "%%c"|FINDSTR "%currentdate%" >nul
 IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
 REM code to zip older file(s)
 )
)
```

Edit 20130419-0932Z : Removed NOT from FINDSTR result processing as advised.

Note that using that set of tokens (2 to 4) assigns %%a to the first, %%b to the second and %%c to the third.

It's safe to break the line at the point indicated for ease of reading

```
for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /T'
  ) do (
 set year=%%c
 set month=%%a
 set day=%%b
 set CurrentDate=%%c-%%a-%%b
 )
```

is another valid popular form.

The string `%%c` in which you have your filename is `ECHO`ed into `FINDSTR` which tries to find the string in `currentdate`. The `>nul` suppresses any output from `FINDSTR` (because we're not interested in it)

The value of `ERRORLEVEL` is set by `findstr` - 0 for not found and not 0 otherwise. Hence, if ERRORLEVEL is 1 (or greater than 1) then the ZIP operation is executed. If it **IS** zero, then the string was found and the ZIP operation is bypassed.

Note also that the form

```
:: comment
```

Is fine outside a `block` command (a series of commands normally in parentheses) but should not be used within a block - use a REM instead there, or you could get unexpected results.

Comment: Thanks a lot. My purpose is solved now. But, I'm not sure how the `IF` block is behaving.

Comment: `IF ERRORLEVEL 1 ( REM code to zip )`  Code to zip is executed if I remove `NOT`

Comment: Quite correct - edited to correct code. Note to self : get more sleep.